# Apply custom function to Rolling Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a function (let's call it) RBSA(df) (that I'm currently treating the function as a blackbox) that takes a dataframe

```
   DATE      RETURN    STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4
2020-09-01    0.01      100       251       300       211
2020-09-02    0.04      106       248       310       210
2020-09-03    0.03      104       251       308       211
2020-09-03    0.02      110       258       306       212
...
```

and returns a dataframe like this

```
DATE       STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4    R2
2020        0.01      85        10        4.99     68
```

Now I want to be able to apply that function on a rolling basis with a window of 30 to the initial database so that the dataframe looks something like this.

```
  DATE       STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4    R2
2020-09       0.01      85        10        4.99     68   #applied date range would be 09-01 to 09-30
2020-09       0.99      80        15        4.01     77   #applied date range would be 09-02 to 10-01
2020-09       3.93      80        10        6.07     89   #applied date range would be 09-03 to 10-02
```

So far I've tried using `df.rolling(30).apply(RBSA)` however from what I can tell the rolling.apply function applies the function by turning each window into a `numpy.ndarray`. However since I'm treating the `RBSA()` function as a black box, I would rather not change the `RBSA()` function to have a `numpy.ndarray` as it's input.

My second idea was to create a for loop that `append()` each dataframe to a, initially, empty dataframe. However, i'm not really sure how to emulate a rolling window using a while loop.

```
def rolling30(df):
   count = len(count) - 30
   ret = []
   while (count > 0):
      count = count - 1
      df2 = df[count:count + 30]
      df2 = style(df2)
      ret.append(df2)
```

However unlike when I manually append the dataframes together, for some reason when I'm appending the dataframes together it seems to create an output that looks like this (notice the comma)

```
  DATE       STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4    R2
2020-09       0.01      85        10        4.99     68, DATE       STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4    R2  
2020-09       0.99      80        15        4.01     77, DATE       STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4    R2   
2020-09       3.93      80        10        6.07     89, DATE       STYLE1    STYLE2    STYLE3    STYLE4    R2
```

Right now it feels like I'm closest when coming to a solution with the while loop. Though it doesn't feel as elegant as using `rolling.apply`

UPDATE: just did a `isinstance(rolling30(df), pd.DataFrame)` and it returned `False`so I assume the problem is that somewhere it's reverting it into something thats not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solution to my `while` loop probem. Realized the initial `ret`was a list and changed that to `ret = pd.DataFrame()` and then the append to call back to `ret`

```
def rolling30(df):
   count = len(count) - 30
   ret = pd.DataFrame()
   while (count > 0):
      count = count - 1
      df2 = df[count:count + 30]
      df2 = style(df2)
      ret = ret.append(df2)
```

I would still like to see what methods other people had to this problem since I feel like the deployment of the While Loop isn't a elegant solution here.